# using multi time frames to plotshape buy or sell

Tags: pine-script

Using one indicator on both 1M and 5M to get a signal only when cross happen on the 1M while the indicator on the 5M is below Zero line.

Created tickerID and security for both 1M and 5M and used crossover() for the 1M and indicator < 0 and combined both.

```
//@version=3
study(title="Sobh-New-HA-Study-Short", shorttitle="Sobh-New-HA-Study-Short", overlay=true)

///////////////// START Getting the HA candle /////////////////

openHA  = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, open)
closeHA = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, close)
highHA  = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, high)
lowHA  = security(heikinashi(tickerid), period, low)
////////////

haTicker = heikinashi(tickerid)
haOpenValue(r) =>  security(haTicker, r, open)
haCloseValue(r) =>  security(haTicker, r, close)
halowValue(r)  => security(haTicker, r, low)
hahighValue(r) =>  security(haTicker, r, high)

Close1MHA=haCloseValue("1")
Open1MHA=haOpenValue("1")
High1MHA=hahighValue("1")
Low1MHA=halowValue("1")

Close5MHA=haCloseValue("5")
Open5MHA=haOpenValue("5")
High5MHA=hahighValue("5")
Low5MHA=halowValue("5")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
study(title="WaveTrend [LazyBear]", shorttitle="WT_LB")
n1 = input(10, "Channel Length")
n2 = input(21, "Average Length")
obLevel1 = input(60, "Over Bought Level 1")
obLevel2 = input(53, "Over Bought Level 2")
osLevel1 = input(-60, "Over Sold Level 1")
osLevel2 = input(-53, "Over Sold Level 2")

////////////////////////////////1MIN////////////////////////////////////////

ap1HA = (High1MHA + Low1MHA + Close1MHA)/3 
esa1HA = ema(ap1HA, n1)
d1HA = ema(abs(ap1HA - esa1HA), n1)
ci1HA = (ap1HA - esa1HA) / (0.015 * d1HA)
tci1HA = ema(ci1HA, n2)

wt1HA = tci1HA          //// Green Indicator
wt2HA = sma(wt1HA,4)   //// Red Indicator

//////////////////////////5MIN///////////////////////////////////

apHA = (High5MHA + Low5MHA + Close5MHA)/3 
esaHA = ema(apHA, n1)
dHA = ema(abs(apHA - esaHA), n1)
ciHA = (apHA - esaHA) / (0.015 * dHA)
tciHA = ema(ciHA, n2)

wt5HAOne = tciHA          //// Green Indicator
wt5HATwo = sma(wt5HAOne,4)   //// Red Indicator

ema2005MHA = ema(Close5MHA, 200)
plot(ema(close, 200),linewidth=4,transp=0,color=orange)

//////////////////////////// SMA 50 //////////////////////////////
lenSimple = input(50, minval=1)
srcSimple = input(close)
sma50 = sma(srcSimple, lenSimple)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
plot(sma50, color=aqua, linewidth=4,title="SMA 50",transp=0)

/////////////////////

PriceCloseAboveSMA50= Close5MHA > sma50
PriceCloseBelow50SMA= sma50 > Close5MHA
BearMarket= ema2005MHA > sma50
BullMArket= sma50 > ema2005MHA
wt5HAOneBelowZero= wt5HATwo < 0
Buy =   wt5HAOneBelowZero and crossover(wt1HA,wt2HA)  
Sell =   crossunder(wt5HAOne,wt5HATwo)

plotshape(Buy ,location=location.top, style=shape.diamond, color=lime, size=size.small)
plotshape(Sell ,location=location.top, style=shape.diamond, color=red, size=size.small)
```

I should get the lime diamond (buy) signal ploted only when the indicator wt1HA cross above wt2HA and ONLY when  wt5HATwo < 0

But what I got is a signal on the 1M when the cross happen regarding if the 5M is above or below zero

I attached the image that show that a signal happen on the 1M (number 1) and (number 2) but as you can see on the 5M on the exact time the indicator is above 0 (number 3 see the zero line). So this signal on the 1M should not be printed as green lime diamond on the 1M .

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of what you expect and what you get? It makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Please edit your question and add new information there.

Comment: done . i edited the original question with  more details and image to show exactly the issue

Comment: anyone can help in this?

Comment: can anyone help in this ?